# VPS MySQL Problem but Where?

Tags: mysql

We have a VPS with around 40 databases and 1 of them is getting very high traffic (selects)... is there any tool that i can install to keep a record or visualize what database is getting the most traffic/hits???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL Enterprise Monitor](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/monitor.html)

> Advanced Query Analyzer - Provides multiple options for quickly finding worst offenders. Collected queries can be sorted and **filtered** by server, **database**, query type, query content. Analysis can be done by current time intervals or by historical date/time range.
>
> MySQL and OS Metric Graphs - Allows DBA to monitor and correlate these metrics: **Database Activity** (Selects, Inserts, Updates, Deletes)

[image]

I believe it has a free trial.